# Ninja Forms - regenerate the form after submission or by a button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ninja-forms

does anyone have any advice on how I may go about regenerating a Ninja form after successful submission or by a button click event?

To explain, I am using a ninja form in a popup/modal. The modal is displayed and form appears when a user clicks on 'enquiry' button. 
Each time a user clicks to open the modal popup containing the form I would like the form to be reset/regenerated instead of showing the success message from a previous submission.

I have tried using CSS to hide the success message and show the form whenever someone clicks the enquiry button. Whilst this displays the form fine, the submit button doesn't seem to work in the same fashion - it still sends mail but it doesn't show the 'processing' message.

Anyone got any advice on a solution I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to edit a setting in the form editor that handles that:

```
Advanced > Display Settings > Clear successfully completed form
```